# Scroll View does not show widgets completely

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

I made a simple application that contains Scrollview.
Inside the Scrollview I have Gridlayout and it contains a lot of buttons.
But I cant scroll my gridlayout all the way down, as if it doesn't let me to do.

Code:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivymd.uix.gridlayout import MDGridLayout
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFlatButton
from kivymd.uix.screen import Screen


class TestApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        screen = Screen()

        sv = ScrollView(size_hint_y=0.7, pos_hint={'x': 0, 'y': 0.1}, do_scroll_x=False,
                        do_scroll_y=True
                        )

        gl = MDGridLayout(size_hint=(None, None), cols=1, minimum_height=1, row_default_height=180,
                          row_force_default=True
                          )

        for i in range(20):
            gl.add_widget(MDFlatButton(text='text'))

        sv.add_widget(gl)

        screen.add_widget(sv)

        return screen


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `MDGridLayout` must adjust its size as children are added. Just add `adaptive_height=True`:

```
    gl = MDGridLayout(size_hint=(None, None), cols=1, minimum_height=1, row_default_height=180,
                      row_force_default=True, adaptive_height=True
                      )
```